# R: Apply substr to each element of a dataframe column

Tags: r

this is my situation:
I have a dataframe and I want to apply the substr function to each element of a specific column. The column I want to manipulate containes expressions like:

```
x = c("name1_01", "name2_02", "name3_01")
df = data.frame(x)
colnames(df) = ("Names")
df["Names"] = sapply(df["Names"], as.character)
df
# Names
# 1 name1_01
# 2 name2_01
# 3 name3_01
```

Now I want to chop off the last 3 digits of each entry in the specific column.
I simply tried substr which doesn't me what I want:

```
df["Names"] = substr(df["Names"], 1,5)
df["Names"]
# Names
# 1 c("name1
# 2 c("name1
# 3 c("name1
```

If I however apply substr to single elements I do get the right result:

```
df[1,"Names"] = substr(df[1,"Names"], 1,5)
df[1,"Names"]
# Names
# [1,] "name1"
```

I already tried around a lot (I also tried sapply for substr) but I don't get it. I am quite new to R and hopefully the solution is quite obvious...

Thank all of you in advance,
Chris!

Comment: `df[["Names"]] <- substr(df[["Names"]], 1, nchar(df[["Names"]])-3)` i.e. use list element indexing `[[` instead of `[`.  At least that's what I do with data frames :)

Comment: A tip: `df` would be much more easily created with `data.frame(Names = x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
substr(df[,'Names'], 1, nchar(df[,'Names'])-3)
```

Or

```
sub('...$', '', df[,'Names'])

sub('...$', '', as.character(df$Names))
#[1] "name1" "name2" "name3"
```

Comment: why does sub work here? shouldn't it replace the first `name1_01` and leave the others alone?

Comment: @rawr It should work because we are replacing specifically the last three elements for each string element.  Suppose, the pattern is different, for example to replace `_` in a string with multiple `_`. then `gsub` is the way to replace all.  `sub('_', '', 'name1_01_01')[1] "name101_01"`

Answer (score 9):

Using `mutate()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Names = substr(Names, 1, 5))
```